# Move object smoothly to position when attaching hinge joint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball that is released from a swinging bar when you tap on the screen. When the tossed ball collides with another swinging bar I add a hinge joint to the ball and attach it to the end of the bar. However, the circle collider responsible for the collision is not at the end of the bar. So, when I hit the circle collision it attaches the ball to the end of the bar BUT it snaps in place. I want it to look like it smoothly moves into place instead of instantly snapping in place.

**How could I move it smoothly to that position?**

This is the script I use to attach the ball when the collision is detected:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class attachBall : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject player;
public GameObject rope;
public HingeJoint2D hinge;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public CircleCollider2D coll;
public GameObject cameraObject;
public float move;
public float x;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {

    if (collider.tag == "rope") 
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        player.AddComponent<HingeJoint2D> ();
        rope = collider.gameObject;
        hinge = player.GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
        rb = rope.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        hinge.connectedBody = rb;
        hinge.connectedAnchor = new Vector2(0,2.5f);
        rope.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
        addPoint.scorePoint();
    }
}

void Update()
{
    x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x;
    cameraObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (x, 0, 0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone placed an answer on here that did not work and then removed it shortly after. However, in that answer I saw:

```
Vector3.MoveTowards
```

That sparked the imagination and I figured it out. My objects are created with pooling. On one of the pooled objects I added an empty object at the end of the bar. Then I got the position of that object as it circled around and moved my player (ball) towards it with Vector2.MoveTowards. I then matched the Vector2 position of the ball and the empty game object and said if they match stop moving and attach my hinge joint.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class attachBall : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject player;
public GameObject endOfLine;
public Vector2 endOfLineCoords;
public Vector2 playerCoords;
public GameObject rope;
public HingeJoint2D hinge;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public CircleCollider2D coll;
public GameObject cameraObject;
public float move;
public float x;
public static bool attach = false;
public static bool connected = false;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {

    if (collider.tag == "rope") 
    {
        attach = true;
        rope = collider.gameObject;
        endOfLine = rope.transform.Find("endOfLine").gameObject;
        addPoint.scorePoint();
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (attach == true && connected == false) {
        moveToPosition ();
    }
    moveCamera();
}

void moveCamera()
{
    x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x;
    cameraObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (x, 0, 0);
}

void moveToPosition()
{
    if (connected == false)
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        //endOfLine = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("endOfLine");
        playerCoords = player.transform.position;
        endOfLineCoords = endOfLine.transform.position;
        player.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (playerCoords, endOfLineCoords, .5f);
    } 

    if(playerCoords == endOfLineCoords)
    {
        connected = true;   
        player.AddComponent<HingeJoint2D> ();
        hinge = player.GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
        rb = rope.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        hinge.connectedBody = rb;
        hinge.connectedAnchor = new Vector2(0,2.5f);
        rope.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
    }
}

}
```

The only issue that I have now is that when I slow down how fast the ball is moving towards the empty game object it sometimes can't match up with it and kind of bounces trying to catch it. I imagine I can fix this by setting an if statement to attach the hinge joint when the ball gets close to the object VS being at the same coordinates as it.

To the one that posted the temporary answer. Thank you =D